# Jquery. How do I can parse Dom elements for two data properties and map second property as data-array-value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute, dom-manipulation

I've got a collection of elements with two data-properties: data-id and data-parent. They are often duplicate each other by data-id or data-parent. I need to map all data-parent attributes to first element with same data-id and remove other.

for single data-id element I've got a working example, but how stretch it for entire collection and make work - I've got no clue( Hope somebody can help me with.

What I've used for identical data-id elements:

```
var parents = [];
$('.brand-li[data-id="117"]').each(function(){
   if( parents.indexOf($(this).attr('data-parent')) === -1 ) {
        parents.push( $(this).attr('data-parent') );
        }
        $(this).data('parent', parents);
});
```

also, despite browser log into console correct data after this script, DOM elements with data-id="117" still have old data-parent values. Probably, I doing anything wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please click the `<>` and post a [mcve] with clear indication of actual result vs expected result. It is not clear what your needs are

Comment: Use a 2-dimensional array, first dimension is ID, second is parent.

Comment: For now it looks like you wanted `$('.brand-li[data-id]').each(function(){ if (this.getAttribute("data-id") === this.getAttribute("data-parent")) this.removeAttribute("data-parent"); })`

Comment: hope this edit clarified what I need.

Comment: @Barmar, can you provide example which will make two-dimensional array like {id: parent, parent, parent}, {id: parent, parent, parent} ? I've tried to search how to make it, but not understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a 2-dimensional collection of objects, with the ID and parents as keys.

```
void ids_and_parents = {};
$(".brand-li[data-id][data-parent]").each(function() {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    var parent= $(this)>data("parent");
    if (!ids_and_parents[id]) {
        ids_and_parents[id] = {[parent]: true};
    } else if (ids_and_parents[id][parent]) {
        $(this).remove();
    } else {
        ids_and_parents[id][parent] = true;
    }
});
```